# How to design bill table with dynamic bill details

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database-design

I have different module such as painting, chasis_repair, over_oiling sections
Each module have seperate bill table for example painting_bills, chasis_repair_bills, over_oiling_bills

Now I have to create bill for Delivery module. delivery module has relationship to other modules (painting, chasis_repair, over_oiling)
Delivery bill is a consolidated bill of painting, chasis_repair, over_oiling section bills and delivery specific billings

Note: painting, chasis_repair, over_oiling section bills and delivery specific  bills are optional.

example 1: A delivery bill contains painting and chasis_repair bills
example 2: A delivery bill contains over_oiling, painting and delivery specfic bills

```
class DeliveryBill < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :date, :total_amount, :discount
  has_many :delivery_detail_bills
end
```

I am confusing to construct delivery_detail_bills model, I have two idea

1)

```
id
date
tot_amount
bill_item_type # name of section as text for example painting/chasis_repair/over_oiling/other
bill_item_amount # for example, respective total amount of painting/chasis_repair/over_oiling/other
bill_item_klass # for example, here I store the respective class name, PaintingBill, ChasisRepairBill...
bill_item_klass_id # id value of respective object
```

by this way, there is no relationship table. I handle delivery specfic billing items by bill_item_type column
If I want to go corresponding bill, I have to build corresponding link using bill_item_klass, bill_item_klass_id columns manually

2)  create has_many :through association table between delivery_bill with painting_bills, chasis_repair_bills

```
class DeliveryBill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :painting_bills, :through => :delivery_bill_painting_bills

  has_many :chasis_repair_bills, :through => :delivery_bill_chasis_repair_bills
  .....
end

class DeliverBillPaintingBill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :delivery_bill
  belongs_to :painting_bill
end

class DeliverBillChasisRepairBill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :delivery_bill
  belongs_to :chasis_repair_bill
end

....
```

Here relationship is very clear but If I follow this way, I couldn't able to handle the bills for "other" because there is no association table for extra/other bill.
this method will increase number of table count

Which one is the best solution with performance wise or is there any other better solution ?

Comment: hmm? is that possible to use method 2 but combining  with method 1? for example, has_many :painting_bills, :through => :delivery_bill_type, then in your delivery_bill_type will store the info which u using in the method 1?

Comment: cheers..This is also good thought...

Comment: Polymorphic Associations will help to solve this issue but I have doubt with other bills because other bill doesn't have any model. will it raise exception/problem if particular model class(_type_ column) and id(_id_ column) is not available. Ref: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations